# Activerecord attribute string reversal and then order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Folks,

I have a situation where I have a string attribute(**name**) in my model which has data in this format:

- dan01
- joel02
- ken01
- raol01

What I want to do is query and order by **name** but I want the order by to use the string in reverse order, that is **dan01** should be considered as **10nad**, wondering what is the best way to do this in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the database you're using, as you'll want to do this at the database layer for performance. Actually, I'd argue you probably want to rethink what you're actually trying to accomplish here, as I doubt this is really the answer you're looking for. *-Jedi Mind Meld-*

Assuming you're using MySQL: If your model is `Person`, your query would be `Person.order('REVERSE(name)')`

You could do it in ruby, ala `Person.all.sort_by{|p| p.name.reverse}` but I really wouldn't recommend that.

Without knowing the full context of what you're doing, I'll hazard a guess that you want to be storing a second integer column that's your sort order or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a MySQL DB in front of me, but you should be able to do something like:

```
Foo.order('REVERSE(name)')
```

The above works in Postgres and should also work in MySQL according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse.